# Jboss 4.2.3 No valid JNDI binding after successful bounded datasource

Tags: jboss, datasource, jndi

I have a strange behaviour of my Jboss Application server. It seems that my application couldn't find datasource as JNDI published resource.

Datasource is correctely declared in a -ds.xml file located in deploy directory and server load it at start time as you can see in logs.

```
16:40:40,197 INFO  [A] Bound to JNDI name: queue/A
16:40:40,198 INFO  [B] Bound to JNDI name: queue/B

16:40:40,198 INFO  [C] Bound to JNDI name: queue/C
16:40:40,199 INFO  [D] Bound to JNDI name: queue/D
16:40:40,199 INFO  [ex] Bound to JNDI name: queue/ex
16:40:40,207 INFO  [testTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testTopic
16:40:40,207 INFO  [securedTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/securedTopic
16:40:40,208 INFO  [testDurableTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testDurableTopic
16:40:40,209 INFO  [testQueue] Bound to JNDI name: queue/testQueue
16:40:40,226 INFO  [UILServerILService] JBossMQ UIL service available at : /127.0.0.1:8093
16:40:40,240 INFO  [DLQ] Bound to JNDI name: queue/DLQ
16:40:40,283 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'
16:40:40,306 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=jdbc/puma' to JNDI name 'java:jdbc/puma'
16:40:40,895 WARN  [JAXWSDeployerHookPreJSE] Cannot load servlet class: org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
16:40:40,896 WARN  [JAXWSDeployerHookPreJSE] Cannot load servlet class: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
16:40:40,898 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/Puma-War, warUrl=.../tmp/deploy/tmp78545726411293045Puma-War-exp.war/
16:40:40,900 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss.web.deployment:war=Puma-War.war,id=1322606236
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Error during deploy; - nested throwable: (javax.naming.NamingException: resource-ref: jdbc/puma has no valid JNDI binding. Check the jboss-web/resource-ref.)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:384)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
    at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: resource-ref: jdbc/puma has no valid JNDI binding. Check the jboss-web/resource-ref.
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.linkResourceRefs(AbstractWebDeployer.java:623)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.parseWebAppDescriptors(AbstractWebDeployer.java:512)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer$DescriptorParser.parseWebAppDescriptors(AbstractWebDeployer.java:878)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:159)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
    ... 112 more
```

Could you please advise ?

Datasource file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>jdbc/puma</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:sybase:Tds:<server_name>:<port_number>/<database_name></connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybConnectionPoolDataSource</driver-class>
        <user-name>login</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
        <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.SybaseExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
        <metadata>
            <type-mapping>Sybase</type-mapping>
        </metadata>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Web application descriptor related content

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/puma</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Kind Regards,
Pape.

Comment: Could you please put your datasource XML file? Futhermore, please provide the web.xml.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added datasource and web.xml content.

Comment: Do you have a jboss-web.xml ?

Comment: I see many jboss-web.xml in my instance. For instance from JBOSS_HOME\server\<instance>\deploy i have one in each of these sub-directories \jmx-console.war\WEB-INF, \jms\jbossmq-httpil.sar\jbossmq-httpil.war\WEB-INF, \management\console-mgr.sar\web-console.war\WEB-INF\, \jbossws-context.war\WEB-INF\ and \http-invoker.sar\invoker.war\WEB-INF\. Which one of these do you want i give ?

Comment: You should have one in your package under /WEB-INF/ directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **jboss-web.xml** as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jboss-web>
     <resource-ref>
         <res-ref-name>puma</res-ref-name>
         <jndi-name>java:/puma</jndi-name>
     </resource-ref>
 </jboss-web>
```

**Datasource Configuration**

```
 <datasources>
     <local-tx-datasource>
         <jndi-name>puma</jndi-name>
         <connection-url>jdbc:sybase:Tds:<server_name>:<port_number>/<database_name></connection-url>
         <driver-class>com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybConnectionPoolDataSource</driver-class>
         <user-name>login</user-name>
         <password>password</password>
         <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.SybaseExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
         <metadata>
             <type-mapping>Sybase</type-mapping>
         </metadata>
     </local-tx-datasource>
 </datasources>
```

**web.xml**

```
 <resource-ref>
     <res-ref-name>puma</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
     <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
 </resource-ref>
```